# Perl - need to copy only function name

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text file which contains following data
INPUT

```
ChainCtrlBuildChain() : ChainController.c
ChainCtrlDumpChain() : ChainController.c
ChainCtrlDumpChanCallback() : ChainController.c
ChainCtrlExit() : ChainController.c
ChainCtrlGetBitStreamChan() : ChainController.c
ChainCtrlInit() : ChainController.c
```

I want to copy only function names into another text file.

OUTPUT NEEDED

```
ChainCtrlBuildChain
ChainCtrlDumpChain
ChainCtrlDumpChanCallback
ChainCtrlExit
ChainCtrlGetBitStreamChan
ChainCtrlInit
```

By using user4035 code

```
  $text =~ s/\s:\s.*//g;
```

I got "()" outside function body like

```
ChainCtrlBuildChain()
ChainCtrlDumpChain()
```

any tips.how can I do it.

I need to make a generalized code coz FUNCTION NAME AND CLASS NAME WILL BE DIFFERENT DEPENDING ON USER INPUT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
perl -p -e 's/\(.*//' input.file
```

Look for an open parenthesis and anything after it, and delete it all.  The `-p` means read the input file arguments or standard input line-by-line, and after each line, print what's left of `$_` after the script in the argument to the `-e` option has executed.

Comment: thanks for the help.I am new to perl and trying to understand regex.

Answer (score 1):

It captures first string from each line and prints it,

```
perl -nE 'say /(\w+)/' file
```

In case that there is also class name before method name (ie. `class::method`)

```
perl -nE 'say /( [^()]+ )/x' file
```

Comment: That works nicely on the example data, but the commentary suggests that there might be class names too, so names such as `SomeClass::MemberFunction()` might appear, in which case, this loses important information.

Comment: this is also nice way to do incase class::method comes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `split` to get the desired part of your input:

```
perl -ne 'print +(split(/\(/))[0] . "\n";' inputfile
```

Comment: While this would work, it's not a very idiomatic way of writing it, I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if(/(.*)\(\)/)' your_file
```

or in awk:

```
awk -F"\(" '{print $1}' your_file
```

Tested Below:

```
> perl -lne 'print $1 if(/(.*)\(\)/)' temp
ChainCtrlBuildChain
ChainCtrlDumpChain
ChainCtrlDumpChanCallback
ChainCtrlExit
ChainCtrlGetBitStreamChan
ChainCtrlInit
> awk -F"\(" '{print $1}' temp
ChainCtrlBuildChain
ChainCtrlDumpChain
ChainCtrlDumpChanCallback
ChainCtrlExit
ChainCtrlGetBitStreamChan
ChainCtrlInit
>
```

Comment: perhaps non-greedy regex for perl, and using newline in output